# python3 selenium find_elements_by_class_name cannot click on each item

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
itemList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('site-piclist_info')
print(len(itemList))
for item in itemList:
    item.click()
handles = webdriver.window_handles
print(handles)
```

line1 works and line2 is processed and get the result
but line4 cannot be processed
the list of handls always contain only one handle; see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHOaT.png).

Comment: Why did you put too many dots in your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Let us see whats happening in your code:

```
itemList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('site-piclist_info')
print(len(itemList))
```

With this we have got a list of all the nodes with `class='site-piclist_info'`

Next:

```
for item in itemList:
    item.click()
```

Here we are trying to click on each and every node in iterations which are within the list irrespective of whether they are actual links or not. But as you mentioned `line4 cannot be processed` that is because the first node with `class='site-piclist_info'` may not be a [**`Link`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032413/python3-selenium-find-elements-by-class-name-cannot-click-on-each-item) or within an `<a>` tag that's why invoking `click()` method doesn't works.

Finally, `list of handls always contain only one handle` that is the handle of the main window which is opened by the **`webdriver`**

A proper solution may be to construct a unique `xpath` or `css` which identifies the proper group of elements through **`find_elements_*`** method and then save in a list to iterate through it.

Comment: thanks for you reply. 
It works when i use find_element_by_class_name.
the first node can be processed with a click()
and then the handle list contains two results
thanks for you advice for using xpath or css but I need to click all the nodes which class name is site-piclist_info

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website in your screenshot. You're actually clicking on a list of `div`s that each contains a link that opens in a new window or tab, depending on browser.

You'll need to click on the links with this class `site-piclist_pic_link` instead.